# Postgresql で boolean のカラムにインデックスを付けてないと非常に遅くなる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

boolean のカラムへのインデックスの追加は偏りが大きくなければ基本的にあまり変わらないと認識していたのですが、インデックスをはっていないと非常に(数百倍)遅くなる現象に遭遇しました。

```
Benchmark.measure{ Company.where(boolean_column_without_index: false).count }
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fbf763319f8 @label="", @real=4.518864024430513, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.010000000000000675, @total=0.010000000000000675>
Benchmark.measure{ Company.where(boolean_column_with_index: false).count }
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fbf75466130 @label="", @real=0.017290733754634857, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.009999999999999787, @total=0.009999999999999787>
```

DBは`psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.9`を使用しています。ローカル環境(`9.6.3`)では同じ内容のデータを使っても現象が再現しません。

`Company`の件数は5000件ほどしかありません、`false`が2,3割程度とそれほど方よりもありません。

とりあえずは必要なカラムにindexを追加することで対処したのですが、

何故このような状態に何故なってしまうのでしょうか？
またどうやって原因を調査すればよいですか？

Comment: インデックスの構成(DBMSとそのバージョン、インデックスの貼り方により変わります)によっては、インデックス情報だけで件数が取得できるのでそれくらいの差が出るのはあり得るんですが、一方の環境だけで発生と言うのがよくわからないですね。両環境で実際に発行されているSQLがどのようなものか調べられましたか?

Comment: まずはVACUUM FULLして両者のパフォーマンスを比べて見てください。なおv9.XのVACUUM FULLはインデックスを貼り直します。

Comment: @OOPer メモリに大量のデータを読み込ませないために`count`を使ったのですが、件数情報もインデックスによっては含まれているんですね。ありがとうございます。インデックスの貼り方の違いについても勉強してみます。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi  恥ずかしながら`VACUUM`, `VACUUM FULL`コマンドについて知らなかったのでどういったコマンドなのか調べてから実行した所、それぞれ`@real`が`0.047`と`0.006`と差はあるものの問題ない速度に収まりました。これからは大量の削除を行ったときなど注意することにします。

Comment: 「あり得る」と言うだけで、今回の事象でそんなことが原因になっているかどうかは全然自信がないんですが。とにかく両環境で実際に発行されているSQLを抽出して(普通なら全く同じはず)、純粋にそのSQLの実行速度の違いを見ると、何か見えてくることがあるかもしれません。

Comment: 少し気になったのですけれども、両者のベンチマークの total time(user + system time)はほぼ同じ(≒0.01s)なのですね。最初のベンチマーク(インデックスなし)の latency がかなり長かったのではないでしょうか。